# $elemMatch (projection) returns selected array element

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
var ids = ['50478c35889a450000000001',  '50478c35889a450000000002'];
var posterIdArray = ['50478c35889a450000000234',  '50478c35889a450000000234']; 
Post.find({_id: {$in: posterIdArray})
  .select({ comments: { $elemMatch: {$in: ids }}})
  .exec(function (err, doc) {
     console.log(doc.comments); //  ['50478c35889a450000000001']    

});
```

// Note: returns only one comment id
//  I need to find a post with some comments restricted by id and filter

Comment: Don't you need to populate the comments field?

Comment: Yes. But First i need to query selected item in the array of "comments "